How to resolve the deprecation warning 'The legacy JS API is deprecated' when using Dart Sass?
I'm getting the following message when building my project in js, but Dart Sass is already up-to-date. What should I do in this situation?
[@localhost frontend]$ npm run lumis:build

.../frontend/gulpfile.mjs

[22:21:55] Starting 'lumis:build'...
[22:21:55] Starting 'lumisClean'...
[22:21:55] Finished 'lumisClean' after 61 ms
[22:21:55] Starting ''...
[22:21:55] Starting 'lumisLayout'...
[22:21:55] Starting ''...
[22:21:55] Finished '' after 17 ms
[22:21:55] Finished '' after 54 ms
[22:21:55] Finished 'lumisLayout' after 58 ms
[22:21:55] Finished 'lumis:build' after 123 ms
Deprecation Warning: The legacy JS API is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.
More info: https://sass-lang.com/d/legacy-js-api
My gulpfile.mjs:
import { deleteAsync } from "del";
import gulp from "gulp";
import dartSass from "sass";
import gulpSass from "gulp-sass";
import autoPrefixer from "gulp-autoprefixer";
import fileInclude from "gulp-file-include";
import replace from 'gulp-replace';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import concat from 'gulp-concat';
import uglify from 'gulp-uglify';
import gulpIf from 'gulp-if';
import fs from 'fs';
dotenv.config()
const { dest, parallel, series, task, watch } = gulp;
const sass = gulpSass(dartSass);
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If anybody here is using gulp this one worked for me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/79180897/6354700

It work in my case :
    css: {
        preprocessorOptions: {
            sass: {
                api: 'modern-compiler',
            },
        },
    },


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

You can silence this warning in gulp using below code
.pipe(sass({
        silenceDeprecations: ['legacy-js-api', 'mixed-decls', 'color-functions', 'global-builtin', 'import'],
        outputStyle: config.isProd ? 'compressed' : 'expanded',
        indentType: 'space',
        indentWidth: 2,
        includePaths: ['./node_modules']
    }).on('error', plugins.notify.onError({ title: 'Error compiling SASS' })))

If you are using vite -
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        silenceDeprecations: [
          'mixed-decls',
          'color-functions',
          'global-builtin',
          'import',
          'legacy-js-api',
        ],
      },
    },
  },

